# sum of array results for 1st, 2nd, 3rd

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to figure out how to use an array formula to index a transaction list and sum the found numbers within a set date range.
I.e. meal card was used 15 times this month.  Need those amounts summed.

I was thinking of an existing formula that searches for the first amount given a certain text match, if only the dates are within A1 and B1 (i.e. 7/1/18, 7/31/18).  Next cell searches for the 2nd occurrence, etc.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$D$2:$D$9000,SMALL(IF(([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$B$2:$B$9000="GREAT LAKES      STUDENT LN ***********0000")+([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$A$2:$A$9000>=$A$1)+([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$A$2:$A$9000<=$A$2)=3,ROW([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$B$2:$B$9000)-ROW(INDEX([Transactions.xlsx]Transactions!$B$2:$B$9000,1,1))+1),1)),"None")
```

Wasn't sure if this formula could be used for a sum function or if it's a whole different setup.

Just as the formula references, transaction file dates are in column A, description in B, and amount in D

Thank you

Comment: You could use a pivot table and then filter the dates with a slicer or a timeline

Comment: What about sumifs() ...

Comment: All the transaction data is actually being filtered into a pivot table.  The area above the table I have setup for more routine tidbits like the number of paychecks and amounts coming in per month, the various outstanding bills and how much is being thrown at them each month.
Wife has a certain way she wants to see it, so I'm trying to work with that scenario

Comment: I had come across a few people talking about sumifs() but I don't have that much experience in excel formulas.  
You fine folks here helped out with that formula I posted above, so I'm back to seek more help for those far more experienced than I!

Comment: for start... you may share us a sample case/data that we can use to test the formula you had posted... ( :